# getMissingCache method not being called in custom Spring CacheManager

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, microservices

I'm currently facing an issue with a custom implementation of the Spring CacheManager, where the getMissingCache method is not being called as expected.

I have a custom CacheManager implementation that extends SimpleCacheManager. Inside this custom implementation, I have overridden the getMissingCache method to create caches dynamically based on cache specifications defined in the application.yml file.

Here's a simplified version of my cache configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CommonCacheConfiguration {
    // ...

    @Bean
    public DynamicCacheManager dynamicCacheManager(CacheProperties cacheProperties, Ticker ticker) {
        return new DynamicCacheManager(cacheProperties, ticker);
    }

    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static class DynamicCacheManager extends SimpleCacheManager {
        private final CacheProperties cacheProperties;
        private final Ticker ticker;

        @Override
        public Cache getMissingCache(String name) {
            // This method is not being called as expected.
            // The code here should create a new cache based on cache specifications in the cacheProperties object.
            // However, it's not being triggered when accessing caches with unknown names.
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Issue:

The problem is that when I try to access a cache with an unknown name (i.e., not explicitly defined in the application.yml), the getMissingCache method is not called. As a result, the cache is not dynamically created as expected.

```
Application.yml:
caching:
  defaultSpec:
    ttl: PT80M
  specs:
    - name: findUserByRole
    - name: findProductByItem
    # I've removed findProduct from here.
```

Question:

Could anyone please help me understand why the getMissingCache method is not being called as expected? Is there something I might be missing or any configuration that needs to be adjusted to trigger the getMissingCache method when accessing unknown caches?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!